# Sticky header (position:fixed) on VF page inside Salesforce1 application running on iOS

Tags: visualforce, salesforce1-app, salesforce1-platform

I have a Visualforce page running inside a Salesforce1 page. The page contains a sticky header (position: fixed, etc.). This works great everywhere except on iOS. If I render the page directly in Safari on the phone (iOS) the sticky header works as expected, but when I view the page inside Salesforce1 the sticky header stops working. It just scrolls with the rest of the page.

I believe it has to do with the page being rendered in an iFrame inside Salesforce1. Similar to this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27083740/why-does-positionfixed-not-work-when-viewed-in-an-iframe-using-an-iphone-or. The fixes I have seen are to set the height and width of the iFrame to 100%. But being inside Salesforce1 that can't be done. Right?

Has anyone encountered and/or solved this issue?

Comment: have you found any solution?

Answer (score 1):

Influenced by [this Stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23083463/7557028) I wrapped all my Visualforce page content inside a `<div id="ScrolledArea"></div>` and added the following CSS to the page:

```css
    #ScrolledArea {
        height: 1px;
        min-height: 100vh; /* Percent of viewport height */
        overflow-y: scroll;
        -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* Allow momentum scrolling */
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

We have also faced same issue in Salesforce1 for IOS.
To resolve the fixed header issue in IOS we have used CSS as well as jquery code.

**HTML Code :**

Contacts

## My Contacts

**CSS:**
.slds-scrollable{
     overflow-y:auto;
}

**Javascript :**

$(document).ready(function(e){

```
        $(".slds-scrollable").attr('style','height:'+($(document).height()-$(".fixedHeader").height()-20)+'px');
```

});